# What does sorting items by "Other" do?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

When viewing the categories for Unrefined Aux Cores, Aux Cores, or Accessories in the item list, there is an option to sort items by "Other". What does sorting items by Other do?

[image: Sorting aux cores by "other"]